# Asp.net MVC5, how to load .hbs file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use (handlebar) .hbs template in ASP.net MVC5 project, but I can not load the .hbs file.

it occurs **HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found**

I load like this,

```
define [
    'hbs!./index'
],
```

and I confirmed the path is fine. `(http://local_host:1460/Scripts/js/apps/index/index.hbs)`

Do I need to set about .hbs extension in somewhere?

Anybody know, please advice me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you need to tell IIS Express how to handle `.hbs`. Just add the following to your project's web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".hbs" mimeType="text/x-handlebars-template" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```